# SQL Server Restore using T-SQL - error '5(error not found)'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

To restore a database data and log files to different drives I am running the following T-SQL:

```
RESTORE DATABASE DbName_BLAH
FROM DISK = 'w:\temp\DbName.bak'
WITH MOVE 'DbName' TO 'm:\DbName_BLAH.mdf',
MOVE 'DbName_log' TO 'l:\DbName_BLAH_log.ldf'
```

And receiving the following errors:

> Msg 3634, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
>   The operating system returned the
>   error '5(error not found)' while
>   attempting
>   'RestoreContainer::ValidateTargetForCreation'
>   on 'm:\DbName_BLAH.mdf'. Msg 3156,
>   Level 16, State 5, Line 16 File
>   'DbName' cannot be restored to
>   'm:\DbName_BLAH.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to
>   identify a valid location for the
>   file. Msg 3634, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 16 The operating system returned
>   the error '5(error not found)' while
>   attempting
>   'RestoreContainer::ValidateTargetForCreation'
>   on 'l:\DbName_BLAH_log.ldf'. Msg 3156,
>   Level 16, State 5, Line 16 File
>   'DbName_log' cannot be restored to
>   'l:\DbName_BLAH_log.ldf'. Use WITH
>   MOVE to identify a valid location for
>   the file. Msg 3119, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 16 Problems were identified while
>   planning for the RESTORE statement.
>   Previous messages provide details. Msg
>   3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating
>   abnormally.

The database restores as expected when I execute:

```
RESTORE DATABASE DbName_BLAH
FROM DISK = 'w:\temp\DbName.bak'
WITH MOVE 'DbName' TO 'w:\temp\DB_BLAH.mdf',
MOVE 'DbName_log' TO 'w:\temp\DbName_BLAH_log.ldf'
```

I have checked permissions on M: and L:. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** Permissions were given to the SQL Server login rather than the SQL Server service account. See answer below.

Comment: What if you try the full UNC path rather than using drive mappings?

Comment: Are those L: and M: drives on the server itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Verify that the account that SQL Server is running under has access to these `L:\` and `M:\` paths.

Comment: Ah! Something simple. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I gave my SQL Server login permissions. Not the SQL Server service account.

Comment: I must add that I have just read my documentation for building another server - this permission issue had already been documented!